# How can I automate adding a new user, using an existing user's groups?

Tags: scripting, sudo, group, useradd

Raspberry pi comes with a default user account that is added to multiple groups:

```
username@hostname:~ $ groups pi
pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio
```

I'd like to script adding a new primary user with the same group membership as the default.  I think this would also be practical for adding new admins to any Unix/Linux system.  Windows has the functionality from ADUC by [Copying an existing account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771231(v=ws.11)).

I believe the script will need to:

1. Use a loop
2. Prompt for existing username (eu) input
3. Store the existing user's current groups as a variable (eg) - `groups`
4. Prompt for new username (nu) input
5. Add the new user with the existing user's groups - `useradd`

I presume this will work to also gain sudo permission, based on [ændrük's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/7484/192800) to a similar question.  Another similar question is [Rahul's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145029/adding-list-of-users-to-multiple-groups) about adding a list of users to multiple groups.

Comment: So, how would you go about to doing that?

Comment: @ilkkachu, I don't know the answer to the question.  I'm trying to figure it out now, but am still green enough to struggle with multi-line comments.

Comment: how disappointing with multi-line comments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37414/145311.  Perhaps Python would be a better language choice than bash.

Answer (score 0):

Given a template user of some sort, like your default `pi` user on Raspbian, etc.

First, create a new user -

```
adduser newuser
```

Then put them in all the same groups as the `pi` user

```
for i in `grep -E "(:|,)pi(:,|$)" /etc/group|cut -f1 -d:`
do
  adduser newuser $i
done
```

Be very careful about giving too much access.  Also, remember that a user has to log completely out and then log back in before group membership really changes.